# Response.Redirect with endResponse = false doesn't redirect immediately

Tags: asp.net, redirect, webforms, response.redirect

I've a button which do a long running process , so I want to redirect to success page until the process completes , here is a code sample :

```
Response.Redirect("Page_URL", false);
Thread.Sleep(100000);
```

**problem:** page doesn't immediately redirect , it waits 100 seconds and then redirect.

any ideas please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the long process work on different thread, then it will redirect instantly.

Alternatively you can use ajax and show the progress to user and then redirect to success page(Will be helpful in case the long process failed and you don't want your users to see success message for failure)

Comment: This is a technique I have used before. If using newer .net framework, then Task.Run is your friend here. The code will run while your page redirects.

Comment: ok i'll use `Tasks` or `Threads` , I misunderstand how `EndResponse` works , Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter will end the response immediately and redirect if you set it to true.  True will cause no more code to execute beyond the redirect but since you have it set to false, the rest of your code will execute and then the redirect will happen and that is why you are experiencing the delay. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information:

> When you use this method in a page handler to terminate a request for
>   one page and start a new request for another page, set endResponse to
>   false and then call the CompleteRequest method. If you specify true
>   for the endResponse parameter, this method calls the End method for
>   the original request, which throws a ThreadAbortException exception
>   when it completes. This exception has a detrimental effect on Web
>   application performance, which is why passing false for the
>   endResponse parameter is recommended. For more information, see the
>   End method.

If you want the redirect to happen after your long process you should setup something to trigger the redirect when the process is done like doing the long process via an ajax call and polling it for progress and then redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

This code did the trick .

```
 Response.Redirect(“Page_URL”, false);

 var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>

                            {

                                // your code here

                            });
```